# Why is Face ID necessary twice to sign into a Google account?

Tags: safari, password, face-id

When I sign in to Google on Safari, Face ID is required twice. First:

> Sign in to google.com with my saved password

Second for a passkey:

> Do you want to sign in "google.com" with your saved passkey...?

Why is Face ID necessary for the first step ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RV2Ru.png))? Google is just asking for my email, not my password, contrary to the Safari caption "Sign in to google.com with my saved password". Can it be avoided?

Answer (score 0):

This is because Google has chosen to implement Passkeys in the wrong way.

When you sign into Google, it prompts your email first and then your Passkey. This means that if you use Autofill on your email, your browser requests an unlock to access your email account (since it still considers it filling the password) then another unlock for your Passkey.

The proper way to do this is to combine the flow. You can see this on Github.com, shown below - it requires my Touch ID once and not a second time.

Google is likely doing this to keep the Passkey interface hidden for accounts not using Passkeys. I expect they plan on rolling this out more completely in the future.

[image: Github Login Flow]